# how to get the position(bytes) in a file from a word

Tags: c, file

how to get the position(bytes) in a file from a word

I want to search a word in a file and get the number how many bytes it is away from the beginning so i can look it up with the function fseek.
example in a file:

```
hello
christmas
door
clock
```

now i want to now the position (in bytes) where door is so i can locate it with fseek. i tried to locate it with strstr() but i need the number of bytes and not the adress.
Or does somebody now to locate the word in a file with the adress

i want this to use in a database where you can search words

Comment: please show the code. `i tried to locate it with strstr() but i need the number of bytes and not the adress` great! so now just subtract the address from the starting address - and you will get the count of bytes between them, i.e. the offset.

Comment: Do you want to know how to do this at all, or how to do this specifically with C code?  We can see — by inspection — that the position of, say, `door` is 16.  Or, we could use `grep -b` ("byte offset") to find this automatically.  If you want to write your own C code to discover these offsets, that's another question.

Comment: Steve Summit i want to know it for C code

Comment: If you've just used `strstr` to successfully discover the address of a substring, you can easily compute the number of intervening bytes by subtracting: `char *text = "hello\nchristmas\ndoor\nclock\n"; char *p = strstr(text, "door"); printf("offset: %d\n", (int)(p - text));`